# How can i use Symfony Messenger without messenger.yml?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-messenger

I'm trying to use Symfony Messenger in my project without Symfony Framework.

```
class MessengerCommandBus implements CommandBusInterface
{
    /**
     * @var MessageBusInterface
     */
    private MessageBusInterface $commandBus;

    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $commandBus)
    {

        $this->commandBus = $commandBus;
    }

    public function dispatch(CommandInterface $command): void
    {
        $this->commandBus->dispatch($command);
    }
}
```

And I want to use it in my Controller (php8)

```
final class DirectionController
{
    public function __construct(
        private CommandBusInterface $commandBus
        private QueryBusInterface $queryBus
    ) {}
    public function createDirection() {
        $this->commandBus->dispatch(new CreateDirectionCommand('Symfony'));
    }
}
```

I put the controller and [bus into](http://direction.web.controller:%20%20%20%20%20class:%20%27Clinic%5CInfrastructure%5CWeb%5CDirectionController%27%20%20%20%20%20autowire:%20true%20%20%20%20%20public:%20true%20%20%20%20Clinic%5CInfrastructure%5CBus%5CMessengerCommandBus:%20%7E%20%20%20#%20%20argument:%20%20%20Clinic%5CApplication%5CCQRS%5CCommand%5CCommandBusInterface%20$commandBus:%20%27@Clinic%5CInfrastructure%5CBus%5CMessengerCommandBus%27) `services.yml`

```
direction.web.controller:
    class: 'Company\Infrastructure\Web\DirectionController'
    autowire: true
    public: true

Company\Application\CQRS\Command\CommandBusInterface $commandBus: '@Company\Infrastructure\Bus\MessengerCommandBus'
```

But of course, I need to create `MessageBusInterface` implementation in `MessengerCommandBus`. With Symfony framework, I can create it with `messenger.yml` but I use the component standalone and I don't have it.
Where I can configure the bus in this case? Should I create a [new MessengerBus](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html) with `$commandBus = new MessageBus([])`,`$queryBus = new MessageBus([])` but it doesn't implement MessageBusInterface or should I configure it in another place? I can't understand [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html) about Messenger ((

Comment: Same issue here, the documentation is a PITA if you don't use the framework... So much about SF being made of decoupled components... It would be awesome if the documentation would also contain a frameworkless guide!